# Erlang Monitor Type

Tags: erlang, monitor

Full discloser: I've only just started learning erlang. So forgive me if I'm being nieve. In the erlang manual the signature for the monitor function is:

```
monitor(Type, Item) -> MonitorRef
```

According to the rest of the documentation:

> Currently only processes can be monitored, i.e. the only allowed Type
>   is process, but other types may be allowed in the future.

Monitor semantics seem pretty inherently tied to processes i.e. it doesn't make sense to monitor something other than a process. Having this extra parameter seems to border on paranoia rather than trying to plan for the future. What are these other things that might be allowed to be monitored in the future?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the designers may have had in mind, but I'd guess remote nodes.

It may also make sense that a process group (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/pg2.html) could be monitored.

Comment: Process groups is probably right. There is already functionality to monitor a remote node (see `erlang:monitor_node/2,3`: http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor_node-2)